# Exit a Screen after a script is finished

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

When a script that I started in a screen is finished can I tell it to close the current Screen it's in?
If so how?
I know I can do "ctrl + a" then k, then y. To kill it but Im not there to issue those buttons.
And I tried adding "exit" to the end of the script which doesn't seem to close it ether.

I also have a script that will auto start another script in a screen, this seems to work, but Im not 100% sure that I got all the syntax right?

```
screen -dm -S "script0$scriptID"; sleep 1; screen -S "fscript0$scriptID" -X screen ./script.sh "$input1" "$input2"
```

Thanks any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command will cause the current session of `screen` to quit:

```
screen -X quit
```

The syntax of the command in your second question looks OK to me. Can you be more specific about where you think there might be a problem?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick.

I don't really know where the problem is, it just seemed a bit inefficient the way I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a stubborn script holding open a screen can be killed by sending it an abort key sequence:

```
screen -X -S "script0$scriptID" stuff "^C"
```